# stuck either calculating correctly, or with code that crashes

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm fighting the problem of either having correct calculations (that's awesome) but crashes if I leave a text field blank in the simulator (not awesome) OR: when coded differently, no crashes for blank text fields (not good) but calculates incorrectly (not good).

here's what I'm trying to do:
get user input for 4 values: fibers counted, blank fibers counted (ok if it's zero), fields counted, and sample volume. I put in defaults hoping to take care of any instances where text boxes are blank, hoping to prevent crashes. then the app calculates fiber density, limit of detection, and sample result. pretty simple for now but I hope to add to this later.

My main problem has been optionals. I've read up on that and done my best to code correctly, but there are times when Xcode forces me into a corner. So my app crashes when text fields are blank. or I can prevent crashes but somehow the default values will get used in the calculations and the actual data is off.

I must be using if-let incorrectly, so I tried what you see in the code below.

I'll put the code below, and as always, thanks for any help, and understanding that I'm new and trying to get these concepts down while being self-taught (besides lessons learned here). Thanks!

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var fibersCountedTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var blankFibersCountedTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var fieldsCountedTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var sampleVolumeTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var fiberDensityLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var limitOfDetectionLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var sampleResultLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func calculateBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    var blankCheck: String?
    var blankFibersCounted: Double?
    var fibersCheck: String?
    var fibersCounted: Double?
    var fieldsCheck: String?
    var fieldsCounted: Double?
    var volumeCheck: String?
    var sampleVolume: Double?
    var sampleResultNumerator: Double?
    var sampleResultDenominator: Double?
    var sampleResult: Double?
    var sampleResultRounded: Double
    var fiberDensity: Double
    var fiberDensityRounded: Double
    var limitOfDetectionNumerator: Double
    var limitOfDetectionDenominator: Double
    var sampleLimitOfDetection: Double
    var sampleLimitOfDetectionRounded: Double

    struct TypicalSampleData {
        let typicalBlankFibersCounted: Double
        let typicalFibersCounted: Double
        let typicalFieldsCounted: Double
        let typicalSampleVolume: Double

        init(typicalBlankFibersCounted: Double = 4.0, typicalFibersCounted: Double = 5.5, typicalFieldsCounted: Double = 100.0, typicalSampleVolume: Double = 555.0) {
            self.typicalBlankFibersCounted = typicalBlankFibersCounted
            self.typicalFibersCounted = typicalFibersCounted
            self.typicalFieldsCounted = typicalFieldsCounted
            self.typicalSampleVolume = typicalSampleVolume
        }
    }

    //this code calculates correctly but crashes if text boxes left empty in the simulator.

    let defaultSampleData = TypicalSampleData()

    //if let blankCheck = blankFibersCountedTextField.text {
      //  blankFibersCounted = Double(blankCheck)
    //} else {
      // blankFibersCounted = defaultSampleData.typicalBlankFibersCounted
    //}

    //blankCheck = blankFibersCountedTextField.text

    //var blankCheckDbl: Double?

    //if let blankCheck = blankFibersCountedTextField.text {
      //  blankFibersCounted = Double(blankCheck)
    //}; blankFibersCounted = defaultSampleData.typicalBlankFibersCounted

    //if let fibersCheck = fibersCountedTextField.text {
      //  fibersCounted = Double(fibersCheck)
    //} else {
      //  fibersCounted = defaultSampleData.typicalFibersCounted
    //}

    if blankFibersCountedTextField != nil {
        blankCheck = blankFibersCountedTextField.text
    } else {
        blankFibersCounted = defaultSampleData.typicalBlankFibersCounted
    }

    if blankCheck == blankFibersCountedTextField.text {
        blankFibersCounted = Double(blankCheck!)
    } else {
        blankFibersCounted = defaultSampleData.typicalBlankFibersCounted
    }

    if fibersCountedTextField != nil {
        fibersCheck = fibersCountedTextField.text
    } else {
        fibersCounted = defaultSampleData.typicalFibersCounted
    }

    if fibersCheck == fibersCountedTextField.text {
        fibersCounted = Double(fibersCheck!)
    } else {
        fibersCounted = defaultSampleData.typicalFibersCounted
    }

    if fieldsCountedTextField != nil {
        fieldsCheck = fieldsCountedTextField.text
    } else {
        fieldsCounted = defaultSampleData.typicalFieldsCounted
    }

    if fieldsCheck == fieldsCountedTextField.text {
        fieldsCounted = Double(fieldsCheck!)
    } else {
        fieldsCounted = defaultSampleData.typicalFieldsCounted
    }

    if sampleVolumeTextField != nil {
        volumeCheck = sampleVolumeTextField.text
    } else {
        sampleVolume = defaultSampleData.typicalSampleVolume
    }

    if volumeCheck == sampleVolumeTextField.text {
        sampleVolume = Double(volumeCheck!)
    } else {
        sampleVolume = defaultSampleData.typicalSampleVolume
    }

    //if let fibersCheck = fibersCountedTextField.text {
      //  fibersCounted = Double(fibersCheck)
    //}; fibersCounted = defaultSampleData.typicalFibersCounted

    //if let fieldsCheck = fieldsCountedTextField.text {
      //  fieldsCounted = Double(fieldsCheck)
    //} else {
      //   fieldsCounted = defaultSampleData.typicalFieldsCounted
    //}

    //if let fieldsCheck = fieldsCountedTextField.text {
      //  fieldsCounted = Double(fieldsCheck)
    //}; fieldsCounted = defaultSampleData.typicalFieldsCounted

    //if let volumeCheck = sampleVolumeTextField.text {
      //  sampleVolume = Double(volumeCheck)
    //} else {
      // sampleVolume = defaultSampleData.typicalSampleVolume
    //}

    //if let volumeCheck = sampleVolumeTextField.text {
      //  sampleVolume = Double(volumeCheck)
    //}; sampleVolume = defaultSampleData.typicalSampleVolume

    //calculate result
    if let fibersCounted = fibersCounted, fibersCounted < 5.5 {
        sampleResultNumerator = (385 * (5.5 / 100))
        sampleResultDenominator = (7.85 * sampleVolume!)
        sampleResult = sampleResultNumerator! / sampleResultDenominator!
    } else {
        sampleResultNumerator = 385 * ((fibersCounted! - blankFibersCounted!) / fieldsCounted!)
        sampleResultDenominator = (7.85 * sampleVolume!)
        sampleResult = sampleResultNumerator! / sampleResultDenominator!
    }

    sampleResultRounded = Double(round(1000 * sampleResult!)/1000)

    //calculate sample limit of detection
    //insert if-let statement here, similar to above?
    limitOfDetectionNumerator = 385 * (5.5 / 100)
    limitOfDetectionDenominator = (7.85 * sampleVolume!)
    sampleLimitOfDetection = limitOfDetectionNumerator / limitOfDetectionDenominator
    sampleLimitOfDetectionRounded = Double(round(1000 * sampleLimitOfDetection)/1000)

    //calculate fiber density
    //insert if-let statement here, similar to above?
    fiberDensity = ((fibersCounted! - blankFibersCounted!) / fieldsCounted!) / 0.00785
    fiberDensityRounded = Double(round(1000 * fiberDensity)/1000)

    fiberDensityLabel.text = String(fiberDensityRounded)
    limitOfDetectionLabel.text = String(sampleLimitOfDetectionRounded)
    sampleResultLabel.text = String(sampleResultRounded)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to approach your task, but here is a very straight-forward method (replace `fieldA`, `fieldB`, etc with your actual @IBOutlet names):

```
@IBAction func calculateBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let defaultSampleData = TypicalSampleData()

    // get the text from fieldA - set it to "" if fieldA.text is nil
    let textA = fieldA.text ?? ""

    // get the text from fieldB - set it to "" if fieldB.text is nil
    let textB = fieldB.text ?? ""

    // if textA CAN be converted to a Double, use it, otherwise use default value
    let valA = Double(textA) ?? defaultSampleData.typicalBlankFibersCounted

    // if textB CAN be converted to a Double, use it, otherwise use default value
    let valB = Double(textB) ?? defaultSampleData.typicalFibersCounted

    // set resultLabel.text to the product of valA and valB
    resultLabel.text = "Result: \(valA * valB)"

}
```

The idea being: make sure you have *default* values for each part of your "equation".

Depending on your actual use-case, of course, you may want to display an Error popup message instead of using default values. But this should get you on your way.

Comment: I'm going to try it as soon as I can! Thanks for the very quick response and for the help! I'll let you know how it turns out!

Comment: DonMag, that worked like a champ. I really appreciate the help. Hopefully one day I'll get good enough at this where I can help you with something.